# Can't View GitHub Source in Visual Studio

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015

I cloned [DotNet/CoreFX](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx) code using Visual Studio 2015 to view Collections source code.

After cloning and opening `System.Collections.sln`, I opened `.cs` files to view sources.

New view opens but I am seeing no source code as shown below for every file.
[image]

What steps do I need to take to be able to view source in Visual Studio? I am able to open the file using Notepad but viewable in Visual Studio 2015.

- If this question doesn't belong in SO, would someone kindly point me to the right place? Thanks.